# How can I include a variable in my nanorc

Tags: nano

How can I get a custom enviornment variable in my `.nanorc` file. I need it for syntax highlighting.
I want `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/.config/nano/*.nanorc` to be my nanorc files.
Sometimes I use different nanorc's in from different config directories for changing the syntax.I just want to change one variable, not my nanorc file.

Answer (score 0):

Use `vim` ?

In all seriousness though, I cannot find any reference to 'variable' or 'environment' in the `nano` manpages.

As a workaround you *could* copy your `nanorc` to `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/.config/nano/nanorc1` and change the appropriate line in the secondary file.

add something like:

```bash
export nano1=$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/.config/nano/nanorc1
alias nano1='nano --rcfile $nano1'
```

to your `~/.bashrc`
This change will load automatically on new shell (terminal) opening
but the first time you may need to `. ~/.bashrc`

then for the primary configuration just start nano with `nano`
and for alternate configuration use `nano1`

This configuration would also allow you to alter anything else in the secondary config and have it only affect the other-syntax-styled configuration.

Maybe you have syntax highlight config for `python` and another for `ruby` so you want the header-bar to be green in the `python` config and red in the `ruby` config as an additional visual indicator of which syntax configuration you launched a particular instance of `nano` with